# How to update the sqlite database in iOS using iPad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sqlite, core-data

I want to do is to update the sqlite database in iOS using iPad. It is possible to drag the sqlite file in iTunes? Just to check if the data from sqlite display correct. I used DB Browser for SQLite.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You'll need to copy the updated sqlite file over to the Xcode project. Then use Xcode to reinstall the app.

Comment: Yes I have the updated sqlite. What steps do I need to make? Thank you.

Comment: Copy the file over the current file in the Xcode project. Then when you build the app it will have the new file.